# @ManyToOne is fetching all columns of join table while inserting new record

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink persistence provider and Hibernate entity manager 4.3.10.Final. I have a @ManyToOne relationship between Employee and Office entities. I'm inserting a new Employee using EntityManagerFactory. The employee instance refers to an existing Office.The code works but the queries show that it is fetching all columns of Office instead of just officeId. How can I fine tune the queries to avoid fetching all columns of Office while inserting a new employee? I tried using FetchType.LAZY on @ManyToOne but it does not work.

Employee.java

```
@Entity  
public class Employee { 

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="employeeSequence",allocationSize=1, sequenceName="EMP_SEQ")    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="employeeSequence")
    private int empId;  

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="DOB")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    private Date hireDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="location") 
    private int location;
```

Office.java

```
@Entity
public class Office { 
    @Id
    private int officeId;

    private String location;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private String zipcode;
```

Code which creates Employee object

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setFirstName(firstName);        
emp.setLastName(lastName);
emp.setDateOfBirth(dob);
emp.setHireDate(hiredate);

Office office = new Office();
office.setOfficeId(officeId);
emp.setLocation(office);
```

SQL queries

```
Hibernate: 
select
     EMP_SEQ.nextval 
 from
    dual

Hibernate: 
select
     office_.officeId,
    office_.address1 as address2_1_,
    office_.address2 as address3_1_,
    office_.city as city4_1_,
    office_.country as country5_1_,
    office_.location as location6_1_,
    office_.state as state7_1_,
    office_.zipcode as zipcode8_1_ 
from
   Office office_ 
 where
   office_.officeId=?

Hibernate: 
insert 
 into
   Emp
     (DOB, FIRST_NAME, hireDate, LAST_NAME, location, empId) 
 values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty common for developers to query their database based on some foreign-key value to get a persistent instances of a relationship when they are saving a new object, something like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  // other stuff removed for breavity
  @ManyToOne
  private Office office;
}

@Entity
public class Office {
  // no relationship back to Employee
}

// some repository method
public Employee save(String employeeName, Long officeId) {
  final Office office = entityManager.find( Office.class, offceId );
  final Employee employee = new Employee( employeeName, officeId );
  entityManager.persist( employee );
  return employee;
}
```

In this case, the persistence provider will query the database to construct an `Office` entity all for the purpose of associating the identifier with the `Employee` when persisted.  As you've noticed, this is not only unnecessary, but can impact performance.

Another solution to avoid the database fetch would be to leverage either `Session#load` in terms of the native Hibernate API or `EntityManager#getReference` for JPA.  For all intents and purposes, they're synonymous in that they accept a class-type and primary key value and construct a proxy that represents the class-type whose internal state will be loaded lazily if accessed.

So by changing the repository method above to:

```
// some repository method
public Employee save(String employeeName, Long officeId) {
  final Office office = entityManager.getReference( Office.class, offceId );
  final Employee employee = new Employee( employeeName, officeId );
  entityManager.persist( employee );
  return employee;
}
```

There should no longer be a fetch against the data store for `Office`.